# Can I scrape an Esri popup with Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, gis, esri

I would like to be able to scrape coordinates or address for every application in this database:
https://edms.deq.louisiana.gov/edmsv2/quick-search-results

There is an Esri-powered map view for most applications with a valid address next to the AI number in this list, and I'm wondering if I can use this popup to scrape the address for the application?

[image: Here is where the location of the Esri map popup]

[image: Here the map shows the AI number and its location]

Can I use Selenium to select to open the popup and then scrape the geolocation data from the Esri map? I'm not even sure where to start with this, unfortunately. Im lightly familiar with RSelenium, rvest, and httr for scraping but am also happy to work in Python if thats the best way forward.